Data in console but not on the UI in React.js
I am able to see my data in the console but not on the UI in React.js where can the problem be?
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const useFetch = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {

        const abortCont = new AbortController()
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/blogs', {signal: AbortController.signal})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)

                if(!res.ok){
                    throw Error('Could no fetch the data for that resource')
                }
                return res.json();
                
            })
            .then(data => {
                setData(data)
                console.log(data)
                setIsPending(false)
                setError(null)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    if(err.name === 'AbortError')
                    console.log('fetch aborted')
                    setIsPending(false)
                    setError(err.message)
                
            }, 1000)
            });
            return() => abortCont.abort()
        }, []);

        return {data, isPending, error}
}

export default useFetch;

I was trying to view my blogs by id and I am receiving a blank page.


There's a small error in your code. You're utilizing a time value in
the catch block, but you can use it in setTimeout instead.

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    const useFetch = () => {
    
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
        useEffect(() => {
    
            const abortCont = new AbortController()
            setTimeout(() => {
                fetch('http://localhost:3000/blogs', {signal: AbortController.signal})
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res)
    
                    if(!res.ok){
                        throw Error('Could no fetch the data for that resource')
                    }
                    return res.json();
                    
                })
                .then(data => {
                    setData(data)
                    console.log(data)
                    setIsPending(false)
                    setError(null)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        if(err.name === 'AbortError')
                        console.log('fetch aborted')
                        setIsPending(false)
                        setError(err.message)
                    
                })
                },1000);
                return() => abortCont.abort()
            }, []);
    
            return {data, isPending, error}
    }
    
    export default useFetch;

